# constructor that creates an object of type <T> from an object of type <T1>

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I need to create a constructor for my class that takes as argument an object of the same class of type `T1` and create an object of type `T`.

The compiler is the one who decides whether the conversion `T1 -> T` can be done.

Eg.: If I have

```
Object<int> o; 
Object<double> o1(o);
```

This should work since it does not lose precision. It should not work the other way around (copying double values in an integer type object).
Can someone please help/tell me how to do this?

Comment: what is your actual problem? correctly deciding whether precision is being lost? how do you define precision for non-integral types?

Comment: Really such cases as conversion from floating-point to integral shouldn't be handled by your class, but rather by the user. It's allowed if you ever want to do it.

Comment: My general problem is: i'm implementing a 2d-like array class it has the index in which the vale is stored (int row int col) and a template value ( the actual value i'm adding to the array). I have to create an array of type T from an existing array of type U. The text for this problem says : delegate to the compiler the casting control (U -> T)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a template copy constructor?

```
template<typename T>
class Object 
{
    template<typename U>
    Object(const Object<U>& rhs) 
        : val(rhs.val()) // initialize appropirate members
    {
        // here you can assert what types U can be
        static_assert(!(std::is_integral<T>::value &&
                        std::is_floating_point<U>::value), 
                   "Can't construct Object<Integral> with Object<FloatingPoint>"); 
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i initially thought something like this but i can't get it to work.
my class is based on a template struct (int i; int j; T val), and in my class is declared like: structName<T> *arr;

Comment: You should've posted all the relevant info in the question so it could be taken under consideration.

Comment: @userbm pointers are not objects; converting pointers is a completely different question than converting objects, and betrays evidence you have a serious design error.